# IIS IP Whitelist based on subdomain

Tags: iis, ip, whitelist

Is there a way I could enable IP whitelisting based on subdomain.

If my root domain is example.com, is there a provision to whitelist IPaddress1 for subdomain domain1.example.com

Root Domain
example.com

Subdomain1.example.com should have whitelist IP as 192.168.2.1

Subdomain2.example.com should have whitelist IP as address 192.168.2.1--5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box IIS does not support this scenario. You would have to write your own module to do this.